# Qual è la differenza tra "verità" e "realtà"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

Ho frequentato un corso di letteratura all'università dove la nostra prof ragionava su questi concetti rispetto a una novella del Decameron. All'inizio della lezione ha esplicitamente detto che dobbiamo fare attenzione perchè in italiano tra i termini "verità" e "realtà" c'è un'importante differenza ma poi non l'ha spiegata e l'ha data per scontata.

Secondo la mia intuizione e quello che ho letto sui dizionari che ho consultato (dizionario dell'Internazionale De Mauro e Treccani) la differenza è che la verità è un concetto astratto, qualcosa è vero e invece la realtà è quel qualcosa che esiste.

Non vorrei entrare in discussioni filosofiche ma solo capire qual è la differenza importante tra i termini.

Comment: Sono un po' confuso. Siamo sicuri che questa domanda sia sulla lingua italiana (piuttosto che una domanda di filosofia)?

Comment: Hai provato a chiedere alla tua insegnante? I due concetti sono molto ampi e con una lunga tradizione filosofica e logica. Magari lei si riferiva a qualcosa di specifico del lessico di Boccaccio.

Comment: Non sono in grado di rispondere ma faccio notare che "osservare la realtà" ha sicuramente un senso. "Osservare la verità" mi suona strano, mi fa pensare a dio o a una rivelazione. Oppure, al contrario, tre è dispari. Vero. Chi mai direbbe reale. O ancora chi deriverebbe la realtà virtuale come verità virtuale?  Spero di aver fornito uno spunto per i più esperti.

Answer (score 1):

Termini come questi possono assumere significati e sfumature diverse a seconda dei contesti culturali, storici, filosofici in cui vengono usati. Sarebbe interessante dunque sapere qual è la novella del Decameron in questione, così da contestualizzare tale differenza di significato. 
Se vogliamo generalizzare e prendere come campo semantico di riferimento il senso comune, l'uso quotidiano che si fa dei due termini, realtà è qualcosa che si conosce con i sensi, che si può indicare e definire esistente perché la si vede, tocca, sente. "Reale" è contrapposto a immaginario, inventato, frutto della fantasia. Verità può coincidere con realtà o anche no. Certe cose possono essere reali ma non vere (es. una banconota falsa) oppure vere ma non reali (es. appunto certi concetti astratti, frutto dell'intelletto).
Se invece ci spostiamo sul piano ontologico, i due termini coincidono. Ciò che è vero è reale e ciò che è reale è vero. È il piano dell'essere, della consapevolezza, lo si conquista con l'indagine interiore e va oltre la mente. Non è un concetto filosofico, ma un'esperienza interiore, ancor più profonda dell'esperienza del mondo esterno fatta con i cinque sensi. Il focus qui non è sul mondo esterno, è sul mondo interiore, sul soggetto. Il quale è l'unica realtà. Il mondo esterno è reale solo in quanto conosciuto dal soggetto, il quale è, per sé, la propria verità. Essa non è un concetto astratto, ma qualcosa di concreto perché è, momento per momento, ciò che il soggetto scopre grazie alla propria consapevolezza. Verità e realtà dunque corrispondono a contenuti diversi solo ammettendo che la fonte del vero sia qualcosa di oggettivo, riferito a sistemi di credenza che dovrebbero essere validi per tutti. Superato tale punto di riferimento, una volta che l'essere umano si riconosce dentro di sé colui che è, non vi è più motivo di credere vero qualcosa di esterno alla propria realtà ontologica "Io sono".

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie per l'intervento, ma trovo che questa risposta rientri in buona parte nelle “discussioni filosofiche” che l'OP chiedeva di evitare.